# KafkaStreams : Number of tasks and regex for source topics

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Lets say we have a KafkaStreams application which is reading data from 2 source topics customerA.orders and customerB.orders. Each topic is having 3 partitions.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream stream1 = builder.stream("customerA.orders")
KStream stream2 = builder.stream("customerB.orders")
//Business logic which has stateless transformations.
```

When i run this application, 6 tasks are created which is expected ( since we have 3 partitions for each topic) : current active tasks: [0_0, 0_1, 1_0, 0_2, 1_1, 1_2]

Since both topic names end with ".orders", i can use regex to read data from the source topics as shown below

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream stream1 = builder.stream(Pattern.compile(".*orders"))
```

But when i run this application using regex, only 3 tasks are created instead of 6 tasks even though we have 2 topics with 3 partitions each : current active tasks: [0_0, 0_1, 0_2]

streams application is getting messages from both the topics.

Why are the number of tasks reduced when we use regex for source topics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the first code, if you don't apply any operation like join, or using same state store between two topics (more precisely between too Stream DSL codes from two KStreams) it'll create 2 sub-topology, so you can have separated task for each topic's partition. So these 2 Topology process in parallel.
2. When your application subscribes multiple topics into one KStream, it'll create a same task for topic's partitions of input topics which have the same partition number so it's co-partitioned (so partition 0 of topic 1 and partition 0 of topic 2 is consumed by the same task), and one particular task only processes one message from one of subscribed partition-i at a time.

Comment: How do we scale out when we use regex approach to subscribe multiple topics ? I wanted to use regex here to avoid rebuild and redeployment of my streams application when ever a new topic with the same naming pattern is added. If i keep adding more topics say customerC.orders, customersD.orders, e.t.c each with 3 partitions each, then i end up with only 3 tasks (max)  processing all these topics. How to handle this scenario ?

Comment: Currently you cannot scale out using reg-ex subscription. It's a known limitation.

Comment: @kartik Matthias is right, you can avoid changing your application by passing topic list add env, or  config in database, and loop through topics list and build each KStream for each topic, but you still have to restart your application

Comment: just FYI: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9282 - ticket about scaling when using pattern subscription