# Kafka Consumer reading from some topics but not others

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application that reads from a set of topics, enriches the messages with some extra data and then outputs onto another set of topics eg:

`topic.blue.unprocessed` -> Kafka Streams App -> `topic.blue.processed`

`topic.yellow.unprocessed` -> Kafka Streams App -> `topic.yellow.processed`

The consumer group is set up with a regex topic pattern and will read topics with the prefix `topic.`

This was working just fine for some time but I recently noticed it had stopped reading messages from some of the topics eg. no messages from `topic.yellow.unprocessed` are being read but `topic.blue.unprocessed` is still functioning fine.

I investigated the logs and could see that the app was still reading from `topic.yellow.unprocessed` a month ago, however there was a large delay of 5 days from when the message appeared on the topic until it was read by the Streams application. Now it is not reading them at all.

Wondering if anyone has an idea why this may be occurring for only some topics - I would expect if there was an issue with the app or consumer ACL that it would affect all topics but I'm not seeing that happening.

I have confirmed `topic.yellow.unprocessed` is deployed and is receiving messages - they just are not being consumed by the application. Debug logs are enabled but are showing nothing.

See below consumer code:

```
    @Value("${kafka.configuration.inputTopicRegex}")
    private String inputTopicRegex;

    @Value("${kafka.configuration.deadLetterTopic}")
    private String deadLetterTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.configuration.brokerAddress}")
    private String brokerAddress;

    @Autowired
    AvroRecodingSerde avroSerde;

    public KafkaStreams createStreams() {
        return new KafkaStreams(createTopology(), createKakfaProperties());

    }

    private Properties createKakfaProperties() {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "topic.color.app");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerAddress);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class.getName());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 86400000);
        return config;
    }

    public Topology createTopology() {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        // stream of records
        KStream<String, GenericRecord> ingressStream = builder.stream(Pattern.compile(inputTopicRegex), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), avroSerde));

        KStream<String, GenericRecord> processedStream = ingressStream.transformValues(enrichMessage);

        processedStream.to(destinationOrDeadletter, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), avroSerde));

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: you have to put more details, put your consumer code!!

Comment: What is `inputTopicRegex`? If you describe the consumer group for the app, do you see lag for that topic, or is it not in the group anymore?

Comment: Is discussed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245051/kafkastreams-number-of-tasks-and-regex-for-source-topics